# How can I filter based on a condition in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
ID val1 val2
a  1  6
a  1  6
a  3  2
a  4  2
a  5  5
b  2  3
b  2  2
c  3  2
c  4  4
c  5  5
c  6  6
c  5  2
c  2  3
```

Using

```
dat <-df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(corr=cor(val1, val2))
```

This calculates the correlation of val1 and val2 for every group. But I want to filter this only for IDs that occur more than 3 times. Basically, I want to calculate the number of occurrence of each ID (eg. a=5, b=2, c=6) and only calculate the correlation for those IDs that have more than 3 occurrences (in this case, b will be ignored as it occurs twice).

This is a part of a large database.

How can I do it using dplyr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you output that doesn't include anything for those cases with less than 2.

```
dat <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(N = n()) %>%
  filter(N >= 3) %>%
  summarise(corr = cor(val1, val2))
```

Comment: dont need the ``ungroup()`` otherwise spot on!

Comment: thanks, edited to drop the unnecessary second group_by

Comment: You also don't need the `mutate` and the `N`. `filter(n() > 3)` will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(.N >2) .(corr = cor(val1, val2)) , by = ID]
#   ID       corr
#1:  a -0.5319061
#2:  c  0.6101702
```